# Generic method set value of base class property

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing a generic method to put set values on the base class

```cs
public class StageOne: DefaultValues
{
    //StageOne properties
}

public class DefaultValues
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

private T SetValue<T>() where T : DefaultValues
{
    T.message = "Good Job";
    T.status = "Done";
    return default(T);
}
```

I get an error on `T.message` and `T.status`; `T` is type parameter, which is not valid in the given context

I have already Googled it and I can't find my answer - please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you talk us through what you want `return default(T);` to achieve?

Comment: i just wanted to return the whole class that i passed into it but the properties of DefaultValue will be modified.

Comment: Where is the object reference for T in SetValue whose properties to be updated? Are you creating a new default one or expecting it as input parameter?

Comment: @RufusL edited it to string.

Comment: @gp. i don't understand your question. I just wanted to changes the value of message and status. So i wont repeat it every time.

Comment: You have to have an *instance* of the type, not just the type itself, in order to set it's properties. For example, you cannot do `DefaultValues.message = "Hello";`, you need to do something like `DefaultValues dvInstance = new DefaultValues(); dvInstance.message = "Hello";`. That's what @gp is asking (see my answer below for examples of what it looks like)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set properties of the generic type, then you need an *instance* of the type. To get an instance we either need to have the caller pass one in as an argument, or create a new one (and if we choose this option, we need to include the `new()` constraint as well):

First option - have the caller pass in an instance of the type (no need for a return value in this case since the caller already has a reference to the instance we're changing):

```
private void SetValue<T>(T input) where T : DefaultValues
{
    input.message = "Good Job";
    input.status = "Done";
}
```

Second option - create a new instance of the type inside the method (note the added generic constraint, `new()`):

```
private T SetValue<T>() where T : DefaultValues, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    result.message = "Good Job";
    result.status = "Done";
    return result;
}
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
private static T SetValue<T>() where T : DefaultValues, new()
{
    return new T {message = "Good Job", status = "Done"};
}
```

Comment: Wow I'm impressed about the values of StageOne didn't reset after i created a new instance of it. 

this works.

only tried second option haven't tried option one.

Thanks.

edit: it was deleted i did just put the setting of values for the property of stage one after i set the default